# How can I fix this problem of automated differentiation with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, automatic-differentiation

I need to compute the gradient wrt a loss for the variables of a defined neural network, the loss is computed correctly but the gradients are None. The code is the following:

```py
variables = self.model.trainable_variables
for var in variables:
   print("{}".format(var.name)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

   y = self.model.predict(states[t])
   y = tf.reshape(y, constants.NUM_ACTIONS)
   loss = y[actions[t]]

grads = tape.gradient(loss, variables)

print("Information about gradients")
for var, g in zip(variables, grads):
   print(f'{var.name}, shape: {g.shape}')
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What is `states[t]`?

Comment: It's a python list of numpy arrays

Comment: and `y[actions[t]]`?

Comment: It's the probability to choose the actions[t] which is a number between 0 and 3 (included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct indexing `y[actions[t]]` is not differentiable, so your loss tensor is disconnected from the graph.

You can rewrite your code to produce the loss for all elements, but use an input binary `mask` to select only one element. This way your final loss is connected to all inputs (`states[t]` and `mask[t]`).

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
   y = self.model.predict(states[t])
   y = tf.reshape(y, constants.NUM_ACTIONS)
   loss = y * mask[t]
```